# Programs Will Not Run In Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

My programs will not run in VS. I can code it, but it will not debug or start. It says:

```
Unable to start program 'C:\Users\Bob\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Crankexe2\Debug\Crankexe2.exe'. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

This goes for all other programs as well.

What is happening?

Comment: did you build your project before running or debugging?

Comment: `The system cannot find the file specified.` Right there.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you open exe file using VS? if you want to open project, please choose sln file. If you want to run this, shortcut `ctrl+f5` or using window explorer go to path "C:\Users\Bob\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Crankexe2\Debug\" and open file "Crankexe2.exe"

Comment: _"Why do you open exe file using VS?"_ - I don't believe that is what the OP is doing.  **OP:** _"I can code it, but it will not debug or start. "_